# Java StringUtils.stripEnd with period, hyphen or underscore

Tags: java, string, apache

I'm trying to strip trailing characters off of a string using `StringUtils.stripEnd`, and noticed if I try to strip `"_FOO"` from `"FOO_FOO"`, this returns an empty string.  For example,

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class StripTest {

    public static void printStripped(String s1, String suffix){
        String result = StringUtils.stripEnd(s1, suffix);
        System.out.println(String.format("Stripping '%s' from %s  -->   %s", suffix, s1, result));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printStripped("FOO.BAR", ".BAR");
        printStripped("BAR.BAR", ".BAR");
        printStripped("FOO_BAR", "_BAR");
        printStripped("BAR_BAR", "_BAR");
        printStripped("FOO-BAR", "-BAR");
        printStripped("BAR-BAR", "-BAR");
    }

}
```

Which outputs

```
Stripping '.BAR' from FOO.BAR  -->   FOO
Stripping '.BAR' from BAR.BAR  -->   
Stripping '_BAR' from FOO_BAR  -->   FOO
Stripping '_BAR' from BAR_BAR  -->   
Stripping '-BAR' from FOO-BAR  -->   FOO
Stripping '-BAR' from BAR-BAR  -->
```

Can someone explain this behavior?  Didn't see any [examples from docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) of this case.  Using Java 7.

Comment: Docs say "strips any **set of characters**". Not sequence of characters. So if you strip `".BAR"` you're saying "strip all `.`, `B`, `A` and `R` characters from the end of the string."

Comment: @khelwood make that comment an answer please :)

Comment: Look at the doc example:
`StringUtils.stripEnd("120.00", ".0")   = "12"` You instead want `removeEnd(...)` which does the following `Removes a substring only if it is at the end of a source string, otherwise returns the source string.`

Comment: You might be looking for [removeEnd](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Removes `substring` from the end.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation and examples present in the StringUtils Javadoc:

```
Strips any of a set of characters from the end of a String.

A null input String returns null. An empty string ("") input returns the empty string.

If the stripChars String is null, whitespace is stripped as defined by Character.isWhitespace(char).

 StringUtils.stripEnd(null, *)          = null
 StringUtils.stripEnd("", *)            = ""
 StringUtils.stripEnd("abc", "")        = "abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd("abc", null)      = "abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd("  abc", null)    = "  abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd("abc  ", null)    = "abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd(" abc ", null)    = " abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd("  abcyx", "xyz") = "  abc"
 StringUtils.stripEnd("120.00", ".0")   = "12"
```

This is not what you want, as it will strip the SET of characters anywhere from the end. I believe you are looking for `removeEnd(...)`

```
Removes a substring only if it is at the end of a source string, otherwise returns the source string.

A null source string will return null. An empty ("") source string will return the empty string. A null search string will return the source string.

 StringUtils.removeEnd(null, *)      = null
 StringUtils.removeEnd("", *)        = ""
 StringUtils.removeEnd(*, null)      = *
 StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", ".com.")  = "www.domain.com"
 StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", ".com")   = "www.domain"
 StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", "domain") = "www.domain.com"
 StringUtils.removeEnd("abc", "")    = "abc"
```

`removeEnd(...)` operates not a set of characters, but instead a substring, which is what you are trying to extract.

Comment: Thanks, should have read it more clearly.  I wish they had the `www.domain.com` example in the `stripEnd` as a clear counter example.  The `120.00` one has it, but it's not as clear (easier to overlook) IMO.

Comment: Yep, but I believe that covers the exact (close enough) type of case you are looking for.